# Getting Vue.js to hide and switch css class synchronously

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a div which is as follows:

```html
<div :class="classSwitch">
 Content of my div here
</div>

<div v-if="showImage" class="col-4">
  Another div here
</div>
```

My Vue.js script is as follows:

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#el",
    data: {
        classSwitch: "col-8",
        showImage: "true",
    },
    watch: {
        step() {
            if (this.step == 6) {
                this.showImage = false;
                this.classSwitch = "col-10";
            } else {
                this.classSwitch = "col-8";
                this.showImage = true;
            }
        },
    },
});
```

The issue is that there seems to be a lag with the dom, what happens is that the first div gets the `col-10` class which then pushes the `col-4` div to the bottom and it then disappears. It looks very poor.
Even though I have specifically structured the code to get rid of the second div and then enlarge the first div to a `col-10`. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you are trying to do.
But i would use a computed properties instead.

```
computed: {
   classSwitch() {
      if (this.step == 6) {
          return "col-10";
      }
      return "col-8";
   },
   showImage() {
      if (this.step == 6) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

If you go with the approach above you should remove the variables from data object

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach would be having just one computed property for showing the image and one inline class binding.
The data section can be removed since it's variables arent used.

```
<div :class="{ 'col-10': step === 6, 'col-8': step !== 6}">
 Content of my div here
</div>
<div v-if="showImage" class="col-4">
  Another div here
</div>
```

```
computed: {
showImage() {
      if (this.step == 6) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```